# Flow Distance Not Calculating for Entire Raster

Tags: arcmap, dem, spatial-analyst, hydrology, flow

I am trying to calculate the height above the nearest stream for an area. The problem is, it only does so for a portion ( the colored area below) of my area of interest. In the pic below, the black and white raster is my DEM that all of the work is based off of. I want my results of the Flow Distance tool to cover that entire DEM. It missed the lower smallest stream entirely, and the lower portion of another.

In Environments > Processing extent and Raster Analysis mask, I have both set to the DEM. How come it won't calculate a value (height above nearest stream) for the entire area?

My inputs to Flow Distance are a raster of the 3 streams shown below, surface raster is the DEM (filled), and I have tried both with and without a directional DEM, matching it correctly to how it was made (D8).

[image]

Comment: So is it flow length (SA tool) or height above nearest drainage (no standard tool)?

Comment: I am using a Spatial Analyst tool called Flow Distance. You can use it to calculate either horizontal or vertical distance.

Comment: Didn't know if 2nd option exist.